# Is there a way to add a line or underline part of a text in a textbox in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a textbox in Access where new items are concatenated with old items. I can add a space between the old and new text using  `me.oldtext & vbCrLf & me.newtext`. But I was thinking it would look better if I could add a line or underline the oldtext so that it acts as a line as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Some suggestions that I found online was

```
me.oldtext.fontUnderline
```

but this does not work

Comment: Can't be done with normal text. Must be a textbox set for Rich Text format.

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, the vbCrLf is not a space but a carriage return and a line feed (which is different than a space) see: https://www.quora.com/What-is-vbcrlf-in-VBA. An idea could be two have the data splitted into two different textboxes, one for the new and one for the old (without knowing the layout of your form is kind of dificult). and have the old one with the property underlined, set to true.

Comment: You can concatenate a bunch of underscore characters in normal text and force them to a new line with vbCrLf but that will not really have appearance of underscored text.